# Doctrine 2 + zf 1.11

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to set up Doctrine 2 to play with ZF 1.11 for a while. I have managed to resolve all errors except one:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\ORM\Configuration' not found in C:\development\porjects\application\Bootstrap.php on line 258
```

Below is the _iniDoctrine() function in the Bootstrap.php file up to the line 258 referred to by the error message:

```
protected function _initDoctrine()
{
$this->bootstrap('autoload');

require_once('Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php');

// Create the doctrine autoloader and remove it from the spl autoload stack (it adds itself)
require_once 'Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';
$doctrineAutoloader = array(new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader(), 'loadClass');

spl_autoload_unregister($doctrineAutoloader);

$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

// Push the doctrine autoloader to load for the Doctrine\ namespace
$autoloader->pushAutoloader($doctrineAutoloader, 'doctrine');

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', realpath(__DIR__ . '/models/'), 'loadClass');
$autoloader->pushAutoloader(array($classLoader, 'loadClass'), 'Entities');

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Symfony', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../library/Doctrine/'), 'loadClass');
$autoloader->pushAutoloader(array($classLoader, 'loadClass'), 'Symfony');


$doctrineConfig = $this->getOption('doctrine');
$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
```

Apparently, the application fails to 'see' the Configuration class (and file). If I manually require the class before the class is instantiated. Another Class/file appears 'unseen'. A 'manual' fix definitely would not do.

The Doctrine folder which contains these files is on my include path. I have scoured the web for ideas. What please would you suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieve to make ZF 1.x & Doctrine 2 working great together using [this application resource](http://borisguery.github.com/bgylibrary/#bgylib-components-bgy-application-resource-doctrine2) it is available on [github](https://github.com/borisguery/bgylibrary) and well documented.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to integrate Doctrine 2 + Zend Framework you might want to use the 'glue' provided by one of the Doctrine developers (Guilherme Blanco)
https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2

If you haven't seen the presentation by Ralph Schindler and Guilherme Blanco, there is one on Slideshare.
http://www.slideshare.net/ralphschindler/zend-framework-1-doctrine-2-6177485

Also, Ralph has a nice example application on Github.
https://github.com/ralphschindler/NOLASnowball/tree/doctrine2-managed-crud#

Answer (score 0):

There's also a great screencast at [ZendCasts](http://www.zendcasts.com) on how to implement Guilerme's adapter. Look for Unit Testing Doctrine 2 Entities.